# Why does the sea horizon line always seems to be at the same height as one's eyes?

Tags: earth, vision

I wonder why, when I look at a sea/ocean, the horizon line always seems to be at the same height as my eyes, no matter how many meters I am above the sea level.

This is something I noticed when I trek, and it happened in many places. It's particularly noticeable when I climb down a mountain, from the peek to the beach.

However, this isn't the case when landing in an airplane (although maybe in the last seconds, I haven't had the occasion to test), it seems one need to "touch the earth" to see this effect. 
Thanks a lot for your help!

Edit:
Here is my understanding of the triangle thing. But it doesn't make any sense as the higher I go, the less far I see. To make it right I should increase the lenght of the two opposite side (cathetus) of the hypothenus but to what extend should I increase them? 
Thanks a lot for your help!

[image]

Second try! Where the earth look s like a "line"... I still don't get it!
[image]

Comment: +1 for a very good question. My suggestion: draw a triangle rectangle with one cathetus horizontal and another vertical (imagine you're are on the top of that cathetus). Now take the horizontal cathetus to be very big. What happens to the angle between that cathetus (horizontal) and the hypotenuse (your line of sight)?

Comment: @PML  +1 to you for introducing me to a new word!  I don't believe "cathetus" shows up in any textbook I've ever owned (and I majored in math and physics).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft English isn't my main language and in my main language we say "cateto" for cathetus. I don't know any other word for it, actually. Out of curiosity, since this comment will most likely be erased, what do you call a side of a triangle rectangle that isn't the hypotenuse?

Comment: @PML, Does you triangle needs to be an isosceles right(rectangular) triangle?

Comment: Well, no =) The triangle is just a simple visualization tool. Obviously you can pick any other kind of triangle to visualize the setup. The rectangular triangle has one advantage, though, at least for me. It's quick to prove my assertion mathematically if one uses the Pythagorean theorem and the definition of cosine.

Comment: Thanks @PML. The thing I have trouble to understand is where the tangent point that intersects my line of sight (cf my schema in the question)

Comment: Hum. I see your confusion. You're schema has one problem: scale. Your altitude will never be greater than the earth radius. Let me make a drawing and gather my comments as a proper answer. Hopefully i'll address your doubt.

Comment: @PML -  the word commonly used in English is "leg."  You may hear people mention the theorem in geometry known as the "hypotenuse-leg theorem," for example.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Ah, I didn't know. I only new the word in my language. So looked it up wikipedia in portuguese, looked the same article in english and thought that it was that the word I was looking for ^^ Thank you. I also learned linguistics today.

Comment: You're right @PML , I have added a new schema where the eath is more to the scale...

Comment: It's called the _Bartley Effect_ (T Mark Bartley 1988 Cape Cod Massachusetts)
not to be confused with the Brucke-Bartley Phenomenon
'it just happens- try it' 'pretty cool'

Comment: @tmark, thanks for this but I couldn't find any reference to the Bartley Effect on google. Do you have one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [picture drawn by docscience](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/139365/26969) is basically correct, but the math that goes along with it was wrong - as a result, the "height of 370000 km" part of the answer is completely off.

The effect you describe is well known by navigators: when you measure the height of the sun or star with a sextant, you actually have to take into account the height of the eye above the water because *even a few meters height difference is enough to affect your position calculation*.

[image]

Now

$$\cos\theta=\frac{r}{r+h}\\
1-\cos\theta = \frac{h}{r+h}$$

And for $h<<r$ and small values of $\theta$, we obtain the approximation

$$h = \frac12 r\theta^2$$

So the angular error as a function of height can be given by

$$\theta = \sqrt{\frac{2h}{r}}$$

A plot of this value looks like this:

[image]

This graph demonstrates why this correction is so important for sextant observations: the initial slope is very steep, and at sea an error of one degree leads to a position error of 60 nautical miles... By comparison, your body's ability to tell "level" from "not quite level" is probably a couple of degrees - so you really need the altitude of a plane (or a high mountain next to the sea) to convince your brain that the horizon you are seeing is not "level".  According to my graph, 1 degree happens at about 1000 meters, and 2 degrees at 4000 meters. That seems consistent with your own observations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My maths abilities aren't that advanced, I will dig into that a bit more, but at least I understand that this can be explained. Thanks so much, this question first occur to me 5 years ago, and since then I wasn't able to get an answer that makes sense. Again thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The construction and calculations below show that if the altitude is very small compared to Earth's radius, the line of sight as measured from local vertical is very near 90 degrees. The Earth's radius is about 6371 km. For the line of sight to fall 1 degree you would have to elevate your point of view by about 370000 km!

[image]

Comment: Please Docscience, could you provide a schema, I am having trouble understanding where is the tangent point that intersects my line of sight.

Comment: @Arone, yes to night

Comment: Thanks, it's easy to add an illustration. Go and edit your question then click on the rectangle that looks like an image in the editor option, just above the text area. StackEchange hosts your image so you don't have to look for a website to host them.

Comment: Are you sure you mean 370000 km? That's over 50 times your stated value of the earth's radius...

Comment: My lesson learned: fools rush in. @Floris has the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it may not happen in a plane is probably because you are tilted with respect to the horizon (even if it may not feel like it due to fictitious forces). "Touching the Earth", you are "forced" by gravity to be straight up, and thus the triangle described in the comment above works.

Also, these kinds of strange properties usually come from an infinity involved. In this case, it's the fact that the horizon is so far away it's almost like standing in an infinite plane.

In the situation of an infinite plane, it's easy to see that you get to the same situation if you climb up to twice your height, than if you scaled all distances by two (because twice infinity is infinity). And it's clear that an overall scaling wouldn't change the direction in which you see the horizon. Or, as they say, if you scaled everything you wouldn't notice it.

Finally, Earth isn't infinite, so you will eventually notice the horizon dropping if you go high enough, but close to the surface (including a mountain) it's very close to the infinite case.

Comment: Yes. Tonight. I'm a Newby to stack exchange so will need to research how to post illustrations. Please bare with me.

Comment: @docscience I doubt you could *bear* being with me when *bare*  :-)

Comment: Oops. I replied to the wrong person. I'll take your word for it.

Comment: The horizon is only about 5 kilometers away.